# Make divs same size as the biggest one inside the parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have this `div` with 3 childs, but one of them has less text than the others, so the image and the button move, I want the position of the image not to be dependent of the size of the text, so it can stay in the same position as the biggest child image.

Parent `position: relative;` and child `position: absolute;` doesn't work, because the image and the button traslape

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div id="child">
    <h5>About us</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec molestie. .</p>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.marijazaric.com/minimalism_responsive/images/picture1.jpg" alt=""/>
    <button>Read More</button>
 </div>
```

SASS:

```
.parent 
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  justify-content: center

 #child
  border-style: solid
  margin-left: 25px 
  margin-right: 25px
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also declare each of the "child" elements as a flex container, you can get the layout you want.

This quick example assumes a parent element with three elements where "child" is a `class` value instead of an `id` value. In each "child" the `p` element is allowed to grow to take all of the available vertical space. The third "child" includes a half-height image to show how the `img` and `button` stay pinned to the bottom.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child h5 {
}

/* should probably be replaced with a class selector */
.child p {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.child img {
}

.child button {
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h5>About us</h5>
    <p> Maecenas aliquet enim ut mi lobortis, a faucibus orci interdum. Suspendisse potenti. Ut lobortis varius fringilla. Nunc nec urna metus. Ut vel ligula rhoncus nulla ultrices egestas ac ut arcu. Cras eu odio est. In quis bibendum arcu. </p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/326x290">
    <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h5>Services</h5>
    <p> Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut dui risus, placerat non lorem vitae, laoreet imperdiet mauris. Aenean eleifend augue vel purus tincidunt egestas. Morbi sagittis neque efficitur posuere fermentum. Fusce non lectus at enim sodales dapibus. Nam congue neque nunc, ut accumsan mauris ornare sit amet. Nulla quis quam ut urna ullamcorper commodo. Curabitur ac elit at urna molestie pulvinar id at nisi. Cras in quam at magna hendrerit fermentum. Vestibulum vel nulla aliquet, molestie ante eu, laoreet quam. </p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/326x290">
    <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h5>Latest news</h5>
    <p> Maecenas a dolor pretium, maximus mi eu, molestie ligula. Donec aliquam mollis eros at sodales. Pellentesque vitae dui feugiat, tempor eros eu, bibendum massa. Nulla accumsan finibus leo, et pellentesque urna vestibulum ut. Nullam arcu lectus, consectetur a varius sed, finibus nec metus. Morbi lorem nulla, maximus vitae mi in, efficitur elementum mi. Praesent sit amet risus est. </p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/326x145">
    <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS version of the code snippet's CSS:

```
.parent
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: center

.child
  border: 1px solid #000
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  width: 30%
  margin: 1em
  padding: 1em
  h5
  p
    flex-grow: 1
  img, button
```

Comment: Thanks!, that worked very well (Y), you are the flex god haha

Comment: @FabianArce no problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with nested flexbox, and use `margin-top:auto` to push the images to the bottom and keep them in the same line.

I added a `<span>` tag around each `<img>` and `<button>`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.item {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.item h5 {
  margin: 0;
}
.item .pic {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.item .pic img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h5>About us</h5>
    <p>Donec molestie.</p>
    <span class="pic"><img src="//dummyimage.com/200" alt="" /></span>
    <span class="btn"><button>Read More</button></span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h5>About us</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
    <span class="pic"><img src="//dummyimage.com/200" alt="" /></span>
    <span class="btn"><button>Read More</button></span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h5>About us</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec molestie. .</p>
    <span class="pic"><img src="//dummyimage.com/200" alt="" /></span>
    <span class="btn"><button>Read More</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like :

```
 <div id="child">
<ul>
    <li><h5>About us</h5></li>
    <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec molestie. .</p></li>
    <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.marijazaric.com/minimalism_responsive/images/picture1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    <li><button>Read More</button></li>
</ul>
 </div>

 SASS:
.parent 
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  justify-content: center

 #child
  border-style: solid
  margin-left: 25px 
  margin-right: 25px

#child li {display:block};
#child ul {display:inline-table;}
```